# extracting bounding boxes from an image and stores it as image?

Tags: python, opencv

I am having an image with a number of bounding boxes. How can I create a separate image for each bounding box in the images.
For example:

[image]

how can I separate 7 and 4 and save them as separate images.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) on your own, and (2) learn [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions around here. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your _specific_ problem. What have you tried so far? Please share any code you have.

Comment: Hint: If you can find bounding boxes,, you can also find their respective co-ordinates. Use opencv to crop the mother image with these co-ordinates.

Comment: if i have 10 bounding boxes in a single image how can i crope Arkistarvh Kltzuonstev.

Comment: if i m having 100 images means each image having 10 bounding boxes i.e overall 1000 bounding boxes so i nee to write a loop and iterte through roi and seperate the each roi

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a hint, let's say you have an image named `frame_1`, and you have a list of bounding boxes `boxes`, what you can do is to loop through the list of `boxes`, and crop the original `frame_1`, here's a quick example:

```
sub_images = []

for (top, right, bottom, left) in boxes:
    # hint: OpenCV image can be treated as a numpy array
    cropped = frame_1[top:bottom, left:right]
    sub_images.append(cropped)
```

And voila! there's your list of sub_images.

But you really need to show your effort (i.e. some code to show your attempts in solving this problem) when you are asking questions in StackOverflow.

---

P.S. this is not a real answer to the question and should be posted as a comment, I couldn't do so not having enough rep, apologies to the SO community.

Comment: i have to crope the list of boxes and store the images separetely UdonNoodle. because for a single i may can get 10 or 15 coordintes and sometimes 100 coordinates i need to separate each coordinate and have to save separetely. is it possible.

Comment: What I can think of is to use a variable as part of the sub_images name, for instance: `for i in range(len(coordinates)): image_name = "img_{}".format(i)`

Comment: will you please provide some code i will check and let you know because i didn't understand your question